# The function field of an affine plane curve has transcendence degree one

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

I am looking for a book which shows that the function field of an affine plane curve has transcendence degree 1.

Sincerely,
Hypertrooper

Comment: An affine plane has dimension two.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown as the title suggests the question is surely about plane affine curves.

Answer (score 0):

By Noether normalization lemma the question reduces to $X = \Bbb A^1$ and in this case the answer is clear.